# How to ignore a character while using aggregate function

Tags: sql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{first,count}
df.groupBy("grp").agg(first(df("col1"), ignoreNulls = true), count("col2")).show()
```

In the above code `col1` of `df` contains a character `N`. I need to ignore that in the same way as `ignoreNulls=true` how to do that.

Comment: Just filter on that character before .groupBy(...)

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{first, count, when}

df.filter(when(df("col1") =!= "N", true).otherwise(false))
  .groupBy("grp")
  .agg(first(df("col1"), ignoreNulls = true), count("col2"))
  .show()
```

- using filter to exclude rows where col1 val = 'N'
- pass filtered DataFrame to groupBy + same aggregation
- using first with ignoreNulls=true to getfirst non-null value in the group + count non-null values in col2

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply,
i don't want to change the value of N to null because after aggregate i need compare N with incoming stream and update with other value, and value may be null also.
So i want to ignore N without changing it to Null

Comment: Hello! I hope this update is helpful

Comment: In the dataframe i have 6 columns and after group by based on id i need first of all columns where value not equal to N.
For example for id 1 we have values for column 1 and for all other columns value is n, so after group by for that id i need to get value for column 1 and for remaining since there are no values i need to get as N only

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{first, when}
val resultDF = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    first(when(df("col1") =!= "N", df("col1")), ignoreNulls = true).as("col1"),
    first(when(df("col2") =!= "N", df("col2")), ignoreNulls = true).as("col2"),
    first(when(df("col3") =!= "N", df("col3")), ignoreNulls = true).as("col3"),
    first(when(df("col4") =!= "N", df("col4")), ignoreNulls = true).as("col4"),
    first(when(df("col5") =!= "N", df("col5")), ignoreNulls = true).as("col5"),
    first(when(df("col6") =!= "N", df("col6")), ignoreNulls = true).as("col6"))
resultDF.show()`

Comment: in this scenario if first(df(col)) != N means it gives result, what if for same id if we have 4 rows and 1st 2 rows of column as N and 3rd row has value. will it return 3rd row?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to get the first element of `col1` that is not `N`. In case there is no other element but `N`, you want to get `N`. I assume that if all elements are null, you want to obtain null.

In that case, let's perform to aggregations. One that ignores `N`, one that does not and coalesce the results:

```scala
val df = Seq((1, Some("N"), 1), (1, Some("N"), 2), (2, Some("N"), 3),
             (2, Some("A"), 4), (3, None, 5)
).toDF("grp", "col1", "col2")

df
    .groupBy("grp")
    .agg(coalesce(
             first(when('col1 =!= "N", 'col1), ignoreNulls = true),
             first('col1, ignoreNulls = true)
    ).alias("col1"), count("col2"))
    .show()
```

```
+---+----+-----------+
|grp|col1|count(col2)|
+---+----+-----------+
|  1|   N|          2|
|  2|   A|          2|
|  3|null|          1|
+---+----+-----------+
```

In case you want to have `N` for the thrid row, one aggregation is enough: `coalesce(first(when('col1 =!= "N", 'col1), ignoreNulls = true), lit("N"))`